# How to use multiple compiled ts files in a node module?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Currently I am trying to use TypeScript to create JavaScript-Files which are then required in a index.js file. I am using VS 2015 Update 3 with node.js tools 1.2 RC. Sadly it is not working like I thought it would.

To begin with here is my initial idea:

I have a node module (to be precise, it is a deployd module http://docs.deployd.com/docs/using-modules/). This module is handling payment providers like paypal or stripe. Now I want to use TypeScript to write interfaces, classes and use types to make it easier to add new payment providers. The old .js files should still be there and used. I want to migrate step by step and use the self-written and compiled .js files together. So I thought I can create .ts files, write my code, save, let VS compile to js and require the compiled js file in another js file. Okay, that is my idea... Now the problem

I have a PaymentProvider.ts file which looks like this

```
import IPaymentProvider = require("./IPaymentProvider.ts"); // Interface, can't be realized in JavaScript, just TypeScript

export abstract class PaymentProvider implements IPaymentProvider.IPaymentProvider
{

    providerName: string;
    productInternalId: number;

    constructor(providerName : string)
    {
        this.providerName = providerName;
    }

    //... some methods

};
```

The other file is PaypalPaymentProvider.ts

```
import PaymentProvider = require("./PaymentProvider.ts");
export class PaypalPaymentProvider extends PaymentProvider.PaymentProvider
{

    constructor()
    {
        super("paypal");
    }
    // more methods
}
```

VS 2015 doesn't show any errors. The js and .js.map files are generated. Now I thought I could require the files and that's it. I tried to use the PaypalPaymentProvider.js like this **const PaypalPaymentProvider = require("./lib/payment-provider/PaypalPaymentProvider.js");** (yes, it is located there) but it's not working. When starting the index.js via node I get the following error:

...\Path\PaymentProvider.ts:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import IPaymentProvider = require("./IPaymentProvider.ts"); Unexpected token import....

I find it strange that this is the error, because JavaScript doesnt't have Interfaces. The compiled IPaymentProvider.js is empty. 
Also I thought that TypeScript is mainly for development and the compiled JavaScript for production. So why it is requiring a ts-file? I thought imports in typescript will be converted to require of the compiled js-file?
Do I need to require all compiled js files and not only the one I currently try to use? (I don't think so...)

To be honest, I think the main problem is that I am new to TypeScript and make something wrong from the very beginning.

Any help/advice? Thanks!

Comment: You need to publish a declaration file `index.d.ts`. Maybe this [article](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4) can help, additionally to the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html).

Comment: Do i really need to publish a declaration file? The article you linked talks about using a typescript module inside another module. But I want to use typescript compiled javascript files in the same node module. The node module has a index.js and some *.ts files, which are compiled to *.js files and these compiled files are required in the index.js file.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood your problem. Actually I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to mix javascript with typescript. Some of the javascript files are "normal" javascript files and others are compiled typescript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution... Thanks to Paelo's links I was able to see that I need to omit the file ending! So the really simple solution was to write

**import IPaymentProvider = require("./IPaymentProvider");**

instead of

**import IPaymentProvider = require("./IPaymentProvider.ts");**

When I changed that in every ts file it worked perfectly!